# (Unit) Test Driven Development

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

I am fairly new to TDD and not so seasoned at unit testing, hence the question.
I have this legacy function written in PHP

```
function foo(){
   x = bar();
   y = baz();
   if (x > y)
     return 'greater';
   return 'lesser';
}
```

If x (value returned by bar()) is always greater than y (value returned by baz()), I will never be able to test for 'lesser' return statement.

What should I do to cover both the test cases and achieve 100% code coverage?
Redefining foo() as foo(x, y) for dependency injection hooks is not an option with legacy code.

Comment: What's the purpose of the function then if it always returns the same thing?

Comment: Let me be more correct. That function returns a greater value only until Xmas :)

Comment: Injecting a function result isn't dependency injection. It's just respecting the OOP rules that assume that each method must do one and only one thing (and so be fully dependent from the others). I'm affraid the only way to unit test all cases is to redefine foo() as foo(x, y)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming `foo`, `bar` and `baz` are all global functions. (If they are part of a class, you want to be using PHPUnit's mocking functionality).

I blogged before about how to use a pecl extension to replace a built-in function:
  http://darrendev.blogspot.jp/2012/07/mock-socket-in-php.html

This article shows a very interesting alternative approach using namespaces:
  http://marcelog.github.io/articles/php_mock_global_functions_for_unit_tests_with_phpunit.html

It appears you will need to wrap your legacy code in a file with a namespace declaration at the top. I don't know if that is a show-stopper for you or not.

Comment: thank you, using namespaces to override global functions is a neat alternative!

Answer (score 0):

Since bar() and baz() do not take input parameters, they are either returning a constant
(and you can immediately refactor foo() to { return 'greater' }  ; or they depend on some
external variable(s). In that case, do something like

```
 function testFooReturnsGreater() {
     setEnvironmentSoBarIsGreaterThanBaz()
     assert ("greater".equals(foo())
 }

 function testFooReturnsLesser() {
    setEnvironmentSoBarIsLesserThanBaz()
    assert("lesser".equals(foo())
}
```

Since you say bar() > baz() unless it's Christmas, the setEnvironmentxxx() fixtures would need to change the program's notion of the current date (hopefully something you can mock, and not the actual system clock).